# Django forms cleaned

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

When I click on save button, my form also saves the html elements. My form looks like this:

```
class ProductPropertyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductProperty
        fields = ('name', )
```

For example if my text is "My input text". The form saves that in the database: `<p>My input text</p>`
What would be the solution to exclude the html `p` elemnts from the saved data?

Comment: This isn't normal textarea or input behavior. Are you using some kind of library like TinyMce on your field ? If so, stop using it. Please post the ProductProperty model's code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `clean` method like so to return the cleaned data:

```
class ProductPropertyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProductProperty
        fields = ('name', )


    def clean_name(self):
            cleaned_name = self.cleaned_data['name']
              
            return cleaned_name
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/)